# How do I pull future events in Google Calendar using JSON for Klipfolio?

Tags: google-calendar-api, klipfolio

I am using Klipfolio and want to create a visualization that pulls events from my google calendar that take place 6 months from present day, and just the events that occur on that day.

I have tried the following query:

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/xyz@group.calendar.google.com/events?timeMin={date.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'00:00:00Z")}&timeMax={date.addMonths(6).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'23:59:59Z")}&singleEvents=true

However it is pulling all events that occur from present to +6 months. Where is my query wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have the timeMin value set to today and your timeMax value set to +6 months so this will pull everything in between these dates. If you set your timeMin value to the same that you have for the timeMax value then it'll only events for the day that is +6 months from today. Note that the hours, minutes and seconds will still be 00:00:00:

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/xyz@group.calendar.google.com/events?timeMin={date.addMonths(6).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'00:00:00Z")}&timeMax={date.addMonths(6).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'23:59:59Z")}&singleEvents=true

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much

Comment: So now the events the Klip is pulling are correct but the date showing up is still for the present date.


concat(datevalue(today(@/timeZone;),"EEEE”, @/timeZone),", ",datevalue(today(@/timeZone;),"MMM dd", @/timeZone))


How do I manipulate the date formula to show the correct date?

Comment: Within the DATEVALUE(), it is using the TODAY() function. You'll need to use DATE_ADD() to shift today forward six months: concat(datevalue(date_add(today(@/timeZone;),month,6),"EEEE”, @/timeZone),", ",datevalue(date_add(today(@/timeZone;),month,6),"MMM dd", @/timeZone))